# Improve SQL statement

Tags: sql, performance, select, join

I am using the following SQL statement to query a database:

```
SELECT
 ID, Date1, Date2, Value
FROM
 data t1
WHERE
 t1.ID = 100 AND Date2 BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0' AND t1.Date1 =
 (
  SELECT
   max(t2.Date1)
  FROM
   data t2
  WHERE
   t2.Date1 <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' AND t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Date2 = t1.Date2
 ) 
ORDER BY
 t1.Date2
```

I am using `SELECT` statements. Is there a better way to improve the SQL statement or rather make it faster by using `JOIN`?

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And, are you sure that the conditions on the dates are correct?  It seems strange that the conditions are different.

Comment: Always Give the Full Information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way using cte and JOIN.

```
;WITH cte_MaxDate
 AS  (
      SELECT  t2.ID,t2.Date2,MAX(t2.Date1) Maxdate1
      FROM data t2
      WHERE  t2.Date1 <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' 
      GROUP BY t2.ID,t2.Date2
      ) 
SELECT  t1.ID, Date1, t1.Date2, Value
FROM  data t1
 JOIN cte_MaxDate m ON   t1.Date1 =m.Maxdate1 AND m.ID = t1.ID AND m.Date2 = t1.Date2
WHERE t1.ID = 100 AND t1.Date2 BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this code but it has not retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join like this

```
SELECT
 ID, Date1, Date2, Value
FROM
 data t1
join  (
  SELECT
   max(t2.Date1) as tDate
  FROM
   data t2
  WHERE
   t2.Date1 <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' AND t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Date2 = t1.Date2
 ) A on t1.Date1 =A.tDate
WHERE
 t1.ID = 100 AND Date2 BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0' 
ORDER BY
 t1.Date2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this code but it has not retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest not to use CTE Please Find Below Link to view why i am saying this

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table

Now you can use this

```
SELECT  t2.ID,t2.Date2,MAX(t2.Date1) Maxdate1 into #Temp 
  FROM data t2
  WHERE  t2.Date1 <= '2010-02-01 00:00:00.0' 
  GROUP BY t2.ID,t2.Date2
```

Now Create Index On Temp Table Using

```
Create Index T on #Temp (ID,Date2,Maxdate1)
```

No Use This

```
SELECT  t1.ID, Date1, t1.Date2, Value
FROM  data t1
  JOIN #Temp m ON   t1.Date1 =m.Maxdate1 AND m.ID = t1.ID AND  m.Date2 = t1.Date2
 WHERE t1.ID = 100 AND t1.Date2 BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00.0' AND '2010-01-31 23:59:59.0'
```

Please Reply

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this code but it has not retrieved data.